# Tracking the year of a policy

Tags: python, mysql, string, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm having a database of insurance policy which contains 2 column of the current and previous policy number.

```
Current policy number | Previous policy number
ABCD-0001             | 
ABCD-0002             | ABCD-0001
ABCD-0003             | ABCD-0002
XYZ-001               |
```

Now I want to track the year of the policy. (NOTE: the policy number is just example. Actually it is random)

E.g: 1st row: the previous policy number is blank => the current policy will be 1st year
2nd row: 2nd year since the previous policy is 1st row (which is 1st year).

I'm starting to use Python and Mysql so I don't have any idea how to track the year of a policy.

With Python, I loop through each row and insert the result into a list. E.g: 1st row is 1st year => insert into list_tracking

```
Current policy number | Previous policy number | Year
ABCD-0001             |                        | 1
```

Then in the next row, if there is previous policy, I get the year of previous policy by using list.index and add 1.

However this way seems complicated and slow when data increasing or updating.
In excel, I can do this easily with combination of if and vlookup:
If previous year is blank then 1 ; if not then vlookup of previous year and add 1 to the vlookup's value.

Please kindly share some new idea in both Python and Mysql or combination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the empty rows blank or they have `Null` in them as values?

Comment: '...Actually it is random)' - so how do you know the year of policy?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel: Yeah, it's Null

Comment: @P.Salmon: Our system designs that when you input the current policy, you have to follow the previous so the database will record the current policy and the previous policy

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select current_policy_number, previous_policy_number, 1 rn 
    from mytable 
    where previous_policy_number is null
    union all
    select t.current_policy_number, t.previous_policy_number, c.rn + 1
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.previous_policy_number = c.current_policy_number
)
select * from cte
```

The recursive `with` clause starts from rows whose previous policy number is `null`, and assigns them row number `1`. Then, it traverses the hierarchical structure from the root to leafs, incrementing the row number as it goes.

Note that recursive queries are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for. I will try to see if this works. Thanks a lot.